# Solo mining on created altcoin: not able to create block

Tags: bitcoind, altcoin, altcoin-development, solo-mining

I have forked the code of an altcoin to play with the param and understand the process [Source here](https://github.com/JustCuriously/locavore).

Now I want to solo mine to create the blocks. The miner is on my PC and the server on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM.
 RPC connection seems to work:

```
http://MyUser:MyPassword@192.168.1.13:25553/    return
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

but I'm not able to generate block (with NSG). 
Mycoind is launched with :

```
rpcallowip=*
rpcuser=MyUser
rpcpassword=MyPassword
rpcport=25553
port=25552
server=1
listen=1
gen=1
daemon=1
externalip=192.168.1.13
```

But nsgminer does not generate me the blocks, I do something wrong ?

From the PC:

```
nsgminer -o http://192.168.1.13:25553 -u MyUser -p MyPassword
```

Give me the return:

```
 [12:34:12] Probing for an alive pool
 [12:34:12] blktmpl error: Unrecognized block version, and not allowed to reduce or force it
 [12:34:12] The network difficulty has been set to 0
 [12:34:12] No suitable long-poll found for http://192.168.1.13:25553
 [12:34:16] Found block for pool 0!
 [12:34:16] Found block for pool 0!
 [12:34:16] Pool 0 communication failure, caching submissions
 [12:34:18] Found block for pool 0!
 [12:36:13] Pool 0 share became stale during submission failure, will retry as user requested
 [12:36:13] Pool 0 share became stale during submission failure, will retry as user requested
 [12:41:10] Started at [2018-03-21 12:34:12]
 [12:41:10] Pool: http://192.168.1.13:25553
 [12:41:10] Run time: 0 hrs 6 mins 58 secs
 [12:41:10] Average hash rate: 0.0069 MH/s
 [12:41:10] Solved blocks: 44
 [12:41:10] Best share difficulty: 0
 [12:41:10] Queued work requests: 13
 [12:41:10] Share submissions: 0
 [12:41:10] Accepted shares: 0
 [12:41:10] Rejected shares: 0
 [12:41:10] Accepted diff1 shares: 0
 [12:41:10] Rejected diff1 shares: 0
 [12:41:10] Hardware errors: 0
 [12:41:10] Efficiency (accepted shares * difficulty / 2 KB): 0.00
 [12:41:10] Utility (accepted shares / min): 0.00/min
 [12:41:10] Work Utility (diff1 shares accepted / min): 0.00/min

 [12:41:10] Discarded work due to new blocks: 3
 [12:41:10] Stale submissions discarded due to new blocks: 0
 [12:41:10] Unable to get work from server occasions: 0
 [12:41:10] Work items generated locally: 0
 [12:41:10] Submitting work remotely delay occasions: 1
 [12:41:10] New blocks detected on network: 1
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

You should run instance of node in atlest two diffrent machine and both of the need to get connected via blockchain.The reason behind need of atlest two diffrent machine is **consensus protocol**. 
To add another node,

> Run same instance of code on second machine add following line in conf
>   file:

```
addnode=*ipOfSecondMachine*
```

> To check if node is conneceted

```
getpeerinfo
```

is what you need

Then go with normal  steps of minning,

ps: if you are trying to mine srypt based coins like ltc then i recommend **sgminer**